# Stop jquery looping function with second click and start from beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a click function, that starts another looping function.

i've looked for many exampels and instructions but don't get the function stopped with a second click on the button.

on jsfiddle, i've build, how it works actually.

my idea is to put a stop action to the clickfunction, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function marsch() {

    $('li').hide();
    <!-- fadeInSequence().stop(); -->
    fadeInSequence();   
}
```

may you please help me

https://jsfiddle.net/t3exdrud/

by the way, it's my very first coding and it would be helpful, if someone gives also advise, if this code causes problems or isn't up to date

Answer (score 0):

You need an outside variable that control if the function is working or not

```
var fadeSequenceON = false;
function marsch() {
    if(!fadeSequenceON){
        fadeInSequence();
        fadeSequenceON = true;
    } else {
        $('li').hide();
        fadeSequenceON = false;
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks for this solution. 

it would work, if the fadeSequenceOn Function wouldnt be a never ending loop. 

So what happens... first i click the button, the function starts but on second click, it only sets the new variable to false and clears all list elements.

is there another way, i can stop the function? maybe with another button?

Comment: Well it's not very clear what you want to do when the stops function it's call. Do you want to freeze the loop?

Comment: 1st click on button -> start loop
2nd click on button -> stop loop + clear 
3rd click on button -> start loop from beginning 
...

actually, it starts with the 1st klick and starts with the second click again but because, the old loop is still running, i get simultane output